# How to add JWT token in JsonRpcProvider url header when connecting to JWT enabled network?

Tags: ethers.js, hyperledger, besu

When connecting to Besu network which enables [JWT public key authentication](https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/HowTo/Interact/APIs/Authentication/#jwt-public-key-authentication), how to add the token to the [JsonRpcProvider](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/) (ethers 5.0.8)? Here is the current code (before adding JWT token):

```
 let provider_url = "http://node-ip:80"   
 const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(provider_url);
 let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);  //<<==generate wallet for the provider above
```

According to the Besu document above, the JWT token can be added in header after Bearer:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJwZXJtaXNzaW9ucyI6WyIqOioiXSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ1c2VyMiIsImlhdCI6MTU1MDQ2MTQxNiwiZXhwIjoxNTUwNDYxNzE2fQ.WQ1mqpqzRLHaoL8gOSEZPvnRs_qf6j__7A3Sg8vf9RKvWdNTww_vRJF1gjcVy-FFh96AchVnQyXVx0aNUz9O0txt8VN3jqABVWbGMfSk2T_CFdSw5aDjuriCsves9BQpP70Vhj-tseaudg-XU5hCokX0tChbAqd9fB2138zYm5M' -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_listening","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
```

Comment: In the same page you linked they mention passing a [ConnectionInfo](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/web/#ConnectionInfo) object instead of the URL, which includes a heraders field.

Comment: `Ismael`, good point! I was paying attention to url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StaticJsonRpcProvider` is needed for connecting to JWT enabled Besu network. Here is the working code:

```
connection.url = GLOBAL.PROVIDER_URL;  //url for besu rpc node
connection.headers = {
   "Authorization" : `Bearer ${ tokenBesu }`  //<<==tokenBesu is the JWT token for authorization
          };
const provider = new ethers.providers.StaticJsonRpcProvider(connection, 2018);  //2018 is network/chain ID
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be a Static provider. `JsonRpcProvider` is sufficient for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since `v4.0.0` you can provide custom headers to a provider by setting them in `ConnectionInfo` object passed to its constructor.

Source: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/257#issuecomment-420090376